# Grails: Redirect to index.gsp that is not in any controller

Tags: grails

In Grails, how do I redirect to my home page (index.gsp) which is not part of any controller?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do a redirect to '/' like this:

```
redirect(uri:'/')
```

Comment: This will only work if there's a UrlMapping for '/' to the index view.

Comment: It will redirect to the root context of the site, however it happens to be defined is up to the application.  The '/' mapping comes standard in URLMappings.

Comment: This even works when the application is in a subdirectory like `example.org/yourapp/`.

Answer (score 7):

Why do you need a [redirect](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) instead of a [render](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html)? `redirect(uri:'/index.gsp')` might do the trick but I think I would just `render(view:'/index')`

Comment: Be careful rendering index directly.  It's okay with simple static content, once you add a controller to pull in data to display on the main page you'll be switching each of those render statements to redirects.  Will that `redirect(uri:'/index.gsp')` give a 404?

Comment: Since he said it's not part of any controller I think it's safe to render it - but if it were to rely on a model from a controller action rendering the view would almost certainly end up throwing an exception due to accessing the missing model.

Comment: I'm looking down the road a bit.  Most non-trivial apps I've developed start off with a static index.gsp and end up with something like `[controller:'home', action:'index']`.  After going back and fixing a bunch of `render(view:'/index')` sprinkled throughout your apps and you feel compelled to help others avoid that mistake.  If it's just a throw-away app then it's no big deal either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting from IndexController, then you should render(view:'/index')